# Why can't I move an app from a service plan to another which share the same resource group and geographical region?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I've an app which is hosted on a service plan on West Europe, which have Resource Group XXX.
The target service plan is still in West Europe, with resource group XXX.

But when I try to move it, I can't see it in the dropdown list.

Is there any other constraints?

[It seems clear](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/app-service-plan-manage.md#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan).

Comment: does your other app service plan based on the same OS?

Comment: @azMantas yes of course. both are windows.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has the app in question been moved before or otherwise existed in a different resource group at one point?

Comment: @dwellman can't have this information, I've got this scenario from an agency :) Is there some sort of logs about the operations did in the past?

Comment: @markzzz Ostensibly logs exist. You'd have to contact Azure Support to verify the resource group for your app is indeed the resource group for your app,